# Non-simple groups $G$ with only non-trivial quotient isomorphic to $G$

Tags: gr.group-theory, set-theory

If $G$ is a group such that every non-trivial subgroup is isomorphic to $G$ itself, then $G= \mathbb{Z}$ is the only infinite group with that property (up to isomorphism). Amongst the finite groups we essentially have $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ for $p$ prime.

Turning arrows around, let us say that a group $G$ has *property* $\text{Q}$ if

> whenever $H$ is a non-trivial group and $s:G\to H$ is a surjective group homomorphism, then $H\cong G$.

Again $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ has this property for $p$ prime. (I don't know whether they are the only finite groups with property $\text{Q}$.) Note that $\mathbb{Z}$ does not have property $\text{Q}$.

**Question.** For which cardinals $\kappa\geq\aleph_0$, if any, is there a [**non-simple**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_group) group with property $\text{Q}$ having cardinality $\kappa$?

**Acknowledgement.** Thanks to Dave Benson for suggesting to consider non-simple groups only.

Comment: Groups with your “property Q” are better known as simple groups. Of course, this is one of the most famous and best-studied notions in group theory. I’m voting to close.

Comment: @HJRW This is not true. For example, Prüfer groups $\mathbb Z(p^\infty)$ have property Q even though they are not simple. Note that the definition does not require $s$ itself to be an isomorphism.

Comment: Here is a [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/768561) question dealing with the non-simple groups in $Q$. (Take home points are: finite generation implies simple, and there are non-abelian countable examples.) Of course, simplicity is enough to answer the stated question [(e.g.)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/409043), so I agree with @HJRW re closure.

Comment: By general universal algebra, any group is a subdirect product of subdirectly irreducible groups that are its quotients, thus every group with property Q must be subdirectly irreducible. In particular, this easily implies that the only *abelian* groups with property Q are $C_p$ and $\mathbb Z(p^\infty)$.

Comment: If the question were to understand the non-simple groups with property $Q$, I think it might not get closed.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: Whether or not property $Q$ coincides with simplicity depends on whether or not the isomorphism is required to be induced by $s$. The question doesn't specify, but since the OP writes "I don't know whether they [$\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$] are the only finite groups with property $Q$", I don't think we can be confident about what the definition of property $Q$ actually is. I stand by my vote to close. Please note that the OP is clearly an enthusastic mathematician, but has a history of asking naïve questions that aren't "research level". This is another one.

Comment: @HJRW The definition is formulated precisely, and does not require $s$ to be an isomorphism. This is clearly intended, as the motivating dual property in the first paragraph likewise does not require the inclusion map itself to be an isomorphism, lest $\mathbb Z$ would not have the property. I am perfectly aware of the OP’s history of non-research-level questions, but that does not warrant arbitrarily changing the meaning of his question to make it more trivial than it is.

Comment: Though I agree that the question as such, “for which cardinals ...”, is immediately answered by the existence of arbitrarily large infinite simple groups; it would have to be reformulated along Dave Benson’s lines to make it research-level.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: since both interpretations of the question are trivial, I’m not sure what the substantive point of disagreement is here. Your reading of the question is just as trivial as mine.

Comment: For every infinite cardinal $\kappa$, the group of even finitely supported permutations of $\kappa$ is a simple group of cardinal $\kappa$. Hence, as @DaveBenson suggested, you should modify the question to *For which infinite cardinals $\kappa$, is there a* ***non-simple*** *group with Property Q having cardinal $\kappa$*?

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion @DaveBenson and also thanks to YCor for making me aware of this.

Answer (score 12):

CW answer.

As already mentioned in a comment, the question was already [asked at MathSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/768561/sort-of-simple-non-hopfian-groups). The property in consideration is "every nontrivial quotient is isomorphic to the group itself".

In summary:

- the trivial group satisfies this property
- simple groups satisfy this property
- as mentioned [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/768729/35400), finitely generated groups with this property are trivial or simple (indeed, every nontrivial f.g. group has a simple quotient). This more generally holds for groups that are finitely normally generated.
- as mentioned [in the same answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/768729/35400) the most obvious nontrivial nonsimple examples are Prüfer (aka quasi-cyclic) groups $C_{p^\infty}$ for $p$ prime. These are the only ones among abelian groups.
- nonabelian nonsimple examples are provided [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1985569/35400). (As the Prüfer groups, they are locally finite; these ones are direct limits of iterated wreath products of finite alternating groups.)

Comment: Thanks for taking seriously my suggestion for reinterpreting the question. The question of understanding the non-abelian non-simple groups with the given property seems like an interesting one that has not really been satisfactorily answered at this point.

Comment: @DaveBenson I don't think I'm "reinterpreting". The question is quite clear, stated twice (in title and body). The meaning of "isomorphic" is clear-cut: "there exists an isomorphism". When somebody uses "is isomorphic" to mean "some canonical map is an isomorphic" it's just ill-stated. I saw little point in using this wrong interpretation to get an uninteresting question.

Comment: That's not what I  meant. I was referring to my comment below the question.

Comment: @DaveBenson I also understood you're referring to your comment *"If the question were to understand the non-simple groups with property Q, I think it might not get closed."* My point is that first I'm not sure I noticed this comment, and also I didn't think of my answer as a "reinterpretation". However, I didn't address the "large cardinal" question in this cw answer, and indeed in this case, as you suggested, the question needs to be modified to ask about only about nonsimple pseudosimple groups.

Answer (score 12):

**References & terminology.**

An algebraic structure is called **pseudosimple** if it has more than one element and is isomorphic to all its nontrivial quotients. This concept was introduced in the paper

Monk, Donald
On pseudo-simple universal algebras.
Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 13 (1962), 543-546.

The main result of the paper is that if $A$ is pseudosimple algebra, then the congruence lattice of $A$ is a well-ordered chain of order type $\omega^{\beta}+1$ for some ordinal $\beta$, and, conversely, for every ordinal $\beta$ there exists a pseudosimple lattice whose congruence lattice is a well-ordered chain of order type $\omega^{\beta}+1$.

A later paper that is closer to the problem on this page is:

Schein, Boris M.
Pseudosimple commutative semigroups.
Monatsh. Math. 91 (1981), no. 1, 77-78.

The main result here is that a commutative semigroup is pseudosimple
iff it is a $2$-element commutative semigroup,
$\mathbb Z_p$, or $\mathbb Z_{p^{\infty}}$ for some prime $p$.
This paper states as a corollary to the main result that an abelian group
is pseudosimple iff it is isomorphic to
$\mathbb Z_p$, or $\mathbb Z_{p^{\infty}}$

Comment: The result on the congruence lattice is very nice!

Comment: The result on abelian groups (which I mentioned in my post, although not aware that it's stated somewhere) is very easy because every nontrivial abelian group either has a finite quotient, or else is divisible and hence has a Prüfer quotient. A similar conclusion holds for modules over any fixed PID